# Unable to install python3-pip in ubuntu 18.04 (python version -> python3.7)

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

On executing `sudo apt install python3-pip` command I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

and on still get the same error after adding the universe repository in `sources.list`.

How can I install `pip` for Python 3.7?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is better suited for https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: okk, i will post it there too . thanks

Comment: as I remeber Ubuntu should already have installed `pip` (with `Python 3`) and you don't have to install it. Eventually you may have to use `pip3` or `pip3.7` to run for `Python 3.7`.

Comment: if you don't have `pip` for your Python then you can download with [getpip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). And run it with Python 3.7 to install `pip` for Python 3.7

Comment: BTW: there is unofficial repo with different versions of Python for Ubuntu (and Linux Mint) - see [DeadSnake](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repo

Comment: did you `apt update` before trying to install?

Comment: there was a problem in source.list , i have downloaded it from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/bionic/sources_72696ab51633d7276a1abaa2ce6a5e48eb283f32.txt and changed it     ... and then i was able to download pip3 using the '''sudo apt install python3-pip''' command

Comment: thankyou all for your valuable comments